# Excel VBA - How Tell The Difference Between 2 WorkBooks With The Same Path in Same The Loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have Monthly reports and they have certain patterned name every month. For example, "Visual report for November 2017", "Visual report for December 2017" and on and on... And in my macro I need to use 2 reports and its is very important to me which one of the is of the previous month and which one is of this month.

So I made a table with the possible names of the report for each month in column A with the "Visual report for.." and the month name and the years in column B and I loop through this cells and look for file with this name in the folder (Should be just 2 files. This month and previous.

My problem is that the variables that of month and year are changing after the second workbook gets opened and I can't copy data of the first workbook because he sets with the path of the second one. If anyone has idea How can I name the first workbook in other way I'll be grateful.

```
here is my code:
Sub Main()

Call initialize
Call name_workbook
End Sub


Sub initialize()

Set MainWB = ThisWorkbook
Path = ThisWorkbook.Path
Set empWS = MainWB.Worksheets("emp")
Set sigilWS = MainWB.Worksheets("sigil")
Set centerWS = MainWB.Worksheets("center)
Set ListsWS = MainWB.Worksheets("Lists")
ListsLR = ListsWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

End Sub
```

Here is the main loop I talked about:

```
Sub name_workbook()

'clear old data
centerWS.Cells.Clear
empWS.Cells.Clear
sigilWS.Cells.Clear

'look for files in the folder and name them
For j = 1 To 3
    For i = 2 To ListsLR
    year = ListsWS.Cells(i, 2).Value
    month = ListsWS.Cells(i, 1).Value
    FName = month & " " & year
    SecondPath = Dir(Path & "\" & FName & ".*xlsx*")
        If SecondPath <> "" Then
            j = j + 1
                If j = 2 Then
                    Set preWB = Workbooks.Open(Path & "\" & SecondPath)
                Else
                    Set nextWB = Workbooks.Open(Path & "\" & SecondPath)
                End If
                If j = 3 Then Exit For
        End If
    Next i
Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you always intend to run it for current month? Or are we looking at several months combinations?

Comment: Is this similar to your prior Creation Date deleted question? If yes, did you try my solution there?

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij we are looking at several months combination. If we will run it in Augost 2018 for example it will open the reports of Augost and July.

Comment: can you not write file names out to the main workbook as you have processed them so that the last row of a particular column will always hold the last month file you dealt with? Then check for this file in the folder and set as last month if found?

Comment: @QHarr No mate, that is another solution I found out myself. Unfortunately your solution didn't work and I deleted the question because many gave me a bad score.

Comment: @QHarr I didnt quite understood your solution now

Comment: Of the two files in the folder, will you have dealt with one of them before?

Comment: @QHarr i need them just to copy data, so yes. I s there any way to do it in the format  I  built?

Comment: I could not post my response in comment so I've posted as answer. Please see if it will help in your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it as an example if you were looking at current month and previous month at the time of run.

```
Sub Test()
Dim strPrevWB As String
Dim strNextWB As String
strPrevWB = "Visual report for " & Format(Application.EoMonth(Date, -1), "mmmm yyyy")
strNextWB = "Visual report for " & Format(Date, "mmmm yyyy")
Debug.Print strPrevWB & "--" & strNextWB
End Sub
```

This can be also adopted for working out any month combination like below which you can put in loop to change `dtReport` variable.

```
Sub Test2()
Dim strPrevWB As String
Dim strNextWB As String
Dim dtReport As Date
dtReport = DateValue("31/08/2017")
strPrevWB = "Visual report for " & Format(Application.EoMonth(dtReport, -1), "mmmm yyyy")
strNextWB = "Visual report for " & Format(dtReport, "mmmm yyyy")
Debug.Print strPrevWB & "--" & strNextWB
End Sub
```

Hth,

Answer (score 1):

If the reports are already named then I would create a Function to parse the Date from the FileName.

```
Function getWorkbookDate(FileName As String) As Date
    getWorkbookDate = DateValue(Replace(FileName, "Visual report for ", ""))
End Function
```

You can then determine which is the which Workbook is which by testing which Date is greater.

```
Sub SimpleExample()
    Const Path = "C:\"
    Dim FileNames(1) As String
    FileNames(0) = "Visual report for December 2017"
    FileNames(1) = "Visual report for November 2017"

    If getWorkbookDate(FileNames(0)) > getWorkbookDate(FileNames(1)) Then
        Set nextWB = Workbooks.Open(Path & "\" & FileNames(1))
        Set preWB = Workbooks.Open(Path & "\" & FileNames(0))
    Else
        Set nextWB = Workbooks.Open(Path & "\" & FileNames(0))
        Set preWB = Workbooks.Open(Path & "\" & FileNames(1))
    End If

End Sub
```

If you had several Workbooks then you could sort the Dates to determine which Workbooks are older.  Here I use a SortedList to place the Workbooks in a collection sorted by date ascending.

```
Sub SortedList_Example()
    Const Path = "C:\"
    Dim x As Long
    Dim FileNames(5) As String
    Dim WBList As Object, item As Variant
    Set WBList = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")

    FileNames(0) = "Visual report for July 2017"
    FileNames(1) = "Visual report for November 2016"
    FileNames(2) = "Visual report for September 2016"
    FileNames(3) = "Visual report for November 2017"
    FileNames(4) = "Visual report for January 2016"
    FileNames(5) = "Visual report for October 2017"

    For Each item In FileNames
        WBList.Add getWorkbookDate(CStr(item)), Workbooks.Open(Path & "\" & item)
    Next

    For x = 0 To WBList.Count - 1
        Debug.Print WBList.GetKey(x), WBList.GetByIndex(x).Name
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]